# Поиск файлов через функцию glob

Tags: файлы, php, функции

Подскажите как задать адрес папки в которой нужно найти нужные файлы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы читали документацию?
Вообще папку можно задать в параметре `pattern`, но если хочется по другому то `chdir($directory)` вам поможет перейти в папку в которой надо искать.

```
    glob('images/*.jpg');
==
    chdir('images');
    glob('*.jpg');
```

Comment: благодарен.